# Java 8 Stream List<Foo> to Map<Date, Map<String,Long>> with conditional groupingBy

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Following class:

```
public class Foo {
    private Date date;
    private String name;
    private Long number;
}
```

I now have a `List<Foo>` which I want to convert to `Map<Date, Map<String,Long>>` (`Long` should be a sum of `numbers`). What makes this hard is that I want exactly 26 entries in the inner map, where the 26th is called "Others" which sums up everything that has a number lower than the other 25.

I came up with following code:

```
data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getDate(), Collectors.groupingBy(e -> {
    if (/*get current size of inner map*/>= 25) {
        return e.getName();
    } else {
        return "Other";
    }

}, Collectors.summingLong(e -> e.getNumber()))));
```

As you can see, I have no idea how to check the number of elements which are already in the inner map. How can I get the current size of the inner map or is there another way to achieve what I want?

My Java 7 code:

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> result = new LinkedHashMap<Date, Map<String, Long>>();
for (Foo fr : data) {
    if (result.get(fr.getDate()) == null) {
        result.put(fr.getDate(), new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>());
    }
    if (result.get(fr.getDate()) != null) {
        if (result.get(fr.getDate()).size() >= 25) {
            if (result.get(fr.getDate()).get("Other") == null) {
                result.get(fr.getDate()).put("Other", 0l);
            }
            if (result.get(fr.getDate()).get("Other") != null) {
                long numbers= result.get(fr.getDate()).get("Other");
                result.get(fr.getDate()).replace("Other", numbers+ fr.getNumbers());
            }
        } else {
            result.get(fr.getDate()).put(fr.getName(), fr.getNumbers());
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The map should help me to realize a table like this:

[image]

But I need to sum the "Others" first.

---

<sub>If you need any more infos feel free to ask</sub>

Comment: not very sure, but seems like you might be looking for `data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getName,
                Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getNumber() >= 25 ? e.getName() : "Other", Collectors.summingLong(Foo::getNumber))))`...maybe you could show us what datatype are you inferring for your result and based on what conditions in a simple for loop to demonstrate better.

Comment: @nullpointer `e.getNumber()` isn't the right thing to do. I posted the java 7 code I try to convert

Comment: Just to double click on the above point, what you are collecting currently is not `Map<String, Map<String,Long>>` as you stated in the question instead it is `Map<Date, Map<String,Long>>`

Comment: @Holger they are unique since they are already summed up for each `getDate`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don’t think that this operation will benefit from using the Stream API. Still, you can improve the operation with Java 8 features:

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Foo fr : data) {
    Map<String, Long> inner
      = result.computeIfAbsent(fr.getDate(), date -> new LinkedHashMap<>());
    inner.merge(inner.size()>=25?"Other":fr.getAirlineName(), fr.getNumbers(), Long::sum);
}
```

This code assumes that the airline names are already unique for each date. Otherwise, you would have to extend the code to

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Foo fr : data) {
    Map<String, Long> inner
      = result.computeIfAbsent(fr.getDate(), date -> new LinkedHashMap<>());
    inner.merge(inner.size() >= 25 && !inner.containsKey(fr.getAirlineName())?
      "Other": fr.getAirlineName(), fr.getNumbers(), Long::sum);
}
```

to accumulate the values for the airline correctly.

---

For completeness, here is how to implement it as a stream operation.

Since the custom collector has some complexity, it’s worth writing it as reusable code:

```
public static <T,K,V> Collector<T,?,Map<K,V>> toMapWithLimit(
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> key, Function<? super T, ? extends V> value,
    int limit, K fallBack, BinaryOperator<V> merger) {

    return Collector.of(LinkedHashMap::new, (map, t) ->
            mergeWithLimit(map, key.apply(t), value.apply(t), limit, fallBack, merger),
            (map1,map2) -> {
                if(map1.isEmpty()) return map2;
                if(map1.size()+map2.size() < limit)
                    map2.forEach((k,v) -> map1.merge(k, v, merger));
                else
                    map2.forEach((k,v) ->
                        mergeWithLimit(map1, k, v, limit, fallBack, merger));
                return map1;
            });
}
private static <T,K,V> void mergeWithLimit(Map<K,V> map, K key, V value,
    int limit, K fallBack, BinaryOperator<V> merger) {
    map.merge(map.size() >= limit && !map.containsKey(key)? fallBack: key, value, merger);
}
```

This is like `Collectors.toMap`, but supporting a limit and a fallback key for additional entries. You may recognize the `Map.merge` call, similar to the loop solution as the crucial element.

Then, you may use the collector as

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> result = data.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getDate, LinkedHashMap::new,
        toMapWithLimit(Foo::getAirlineName, Foo::getNumbers, 25, "Other", Long::sum)));
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It's working perfectly fine! Yet, would it even be possible to get the size of the inner map in streams? Or is that totally impossible?

Comment: You would have to implement a custom collector. That wouldn’t be simpler, as that collector would basically contain the same code as above `merge` call in its accumulator function, but you would have to write a combiner function additionally to that.

Comment: I'll try to award an bounty to your answer. Its very nice

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late :) But I come with this Java 8 solution without using the for loop or the custom collector. It is based on `collectingAndThen` which allows you to transform the result of collecting operation.

It allows me to divide the stream in finisher operation based on treshold.

However, I am not sure about the performance.

```
 int treshold = 25


 Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> result = data.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getDate,
            collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), x -> {
                if (x.size() >= treshold) {
                    Map<String, Long> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
                    resultMap.putAll(x.subList(0, treshold).stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getName, Collectors.summingLong(Foo::getNumber))));
                    resultMap.putAll(x.subList(treshold, x.size()).stream().collect(groupingBy(y -> "Other", Collectors.summingLong(Foo::getNumber))));
                    return resultMap;
                } else {
                    return x.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getName, Collectors.summingLong(Foo::getNumber)));
                }
            })));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's simplify the original problem by adapting it to java 8 without using Streams.

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> result = new LinkedHashMap();
for (Foo fr : data) {
    Map<String, Long> map = result.getOrDefault(fr.getDate(), new LinkedHashMap());
    if (map.size() >= 25) {
        Long value = map.getOrDefault("Other", 0L); // getOrDefault from 1.8
        map.put("Other", value + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(fr.getName(), fr.getNumber());
    }
    result.put(fr.getDate(), map);
}
```

And now using Stream

```
int limit = 25;
Map<Date, Map<String, Long>> collect = data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getDate))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, v -> {
        Map<String, Long> c = v.getValue().stream()
                .limit(limit)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getName, Foo::getNumber));
        long remaining = v.getValue().size() - limit;
        if (remaining > 0) {
            c.put("Other", remaining);
        }
        return c;
    }));
```

Comment: You can replace the `getOrDefault` in line 3 by `computeIfAbsent` and then remove the 10th line. Line 5 and 6 can be simplified to `map.merge("Other", 0L, (oldV, value0) -> ++oldV);`. And please instantiate generic types with the `<>` diamond.